# How to override a file field on webform form?

Tags: 7, entities, webforms, theming

I have a webform with a file field printed on an overrided webform template like this:

```
<div class="field-archivos"><?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['archivos']); ?></div>
```

I want to hide the "browse" button and the message "not file selected" in the input (see image below).

[image]

I want to show the input rectangle without message or, in a better case, only a message in the input field that says "click here to upload your file".

Is it possible to override the file field to do what I want?

Comment: i'm working on drupal 7

Comment: Webform 3.x uses Drupal's 'managed_file' widget. Nothing special about that; file upload widgets are notoriously hard to customize. Maybe try this approach: https://www.drupal.org/node/1421750#comment-9397825